# Traefik forward auth per frontend

Tags: go, traefik

I am trying to divide microservices and their auth.

Demo config is looks like:

```
 [frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  entryPoints = ["http"]
  backend = "rancher1"
  passHostHeader = true
  forwardAuth = "http://127.0.0.1:8090"
   [frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
    rule = "PathPrefixStrip:/order"


 [frontends.rancher2]
  backend = "rancher2"
  passHostHeader = true
  [frontends.rancher2.routes.test_1]
   rule = "PathPrefixStrip:/test"
```

How to apply forwardAuth to `frontends.frontend1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Daniel](https://github.com/dniel) he helped me.

So, it's really easy to do:

1. Check your traefik version its should be at least 1.7 (i am not sure in which version this feature was added but its working in 1.7 and 1.7.1).
2. Make your config like this:

   `[frontends.service]
    backend = "service"
     passHostHeader = true
     [frontends.ordersWorker.auth.forward]
        address = "http://127.0.0.1:8090"`